# Operation in every browser the same way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem. This code works well only in Google Chrome. I need it to work well in any other browser. Does anyone know how to do it and help me? I need the code to work well in firefox. Because when you open a script in the Firefox browser, the key (TAB) is detected as a letter. and I can not freely switch between columns

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>



<script type="text/javascript" >

function preventNonNumericalInput(e){var n=void 0===(e=e||window.event).which?e.keyCode:e.which;String.fromCharCode(n).match(/^[0-9,\b,-]+$/)||(alert("WPISZ LICZBĘ"),e.preventDefault())}!function(n){n.fn.average=function(){var e=0;return this.each(function(){e+=parseFloat(n(this).val())}),e/n(this).length}}(jQuery),$(document).ready(function(){$(":reset")}),$(document).ready(function(){$("#calc").click(function(){var e=$("input[type='number']").average();console.debug(e),$("#result").html(e)}),$(".reset").on("click",function(){$("#result").html(" ")})});

</script>


<h1>Oblicz średnią:</h1>
<form action="">
<input onkeypress="preventNonNumericalInput(event)" type="number">
<input onkeypress="preventNonNumericalInput(event)" type="number">
<input onkeypress="preventNonNumericalInput(event)" type="number">
<div id="result" type="reset" ></div><br>
<input type="button" id="calc" value="Licz">
<input type="reset"  value="Reset"  class="reset">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Detect the TAB character, and don't prevent the default action if TAB detected ...

Comment: @Teemu How ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you've put a bit of Javascript to disallow the user to use anything else than numerical inputs into the form, right ? Hence pressing any other key than the 0-9 one while in the input launch your alert : "WPISZ LICZBĘ".

First of all, you want to "unminify" your unreadable Javascript line.

```
function preventNonNumericalInput(e) {
    var n = void 0 === (e = e || window.event).which ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    String.fromCharCode(n).match(/^[0-9,\b,-]+$/) || (alert("WPISZ LICZBĘ"), e.preventDefault())
}! function(n) {
    n.fn.average = function() {
        var e = 0;
        return this.each(function() {
            e += parseFloat(n(this).val())
        }), e / n(this).length
    }
}(jQuery), $(document).ready(function() {
    $(":reset")
}), $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calc").click(function() {
        var e = $("input[type='number']").average();
        console.debug(e), $("#result").html(e)
    }), $(".reset").on("click", function() {
        $("#result").html(" ")
    })
});
```

This line :

```
String.fromCharCode(n).match(/^[0-9,\b,-]+$/) || (alert("WPISZ LICZBĘ"), e.preventDefault())
```

Reads the input and sees if it is a number (0-9) or an hyphen. If you add `|| e.keyCode == 9` it lets you use the tab button.

```
String.fromCharCode(n).match(/^[0-9,\b,-]+$/) || e.keyCode == 9|| (alert("WPISZ LICZBĘ"), e.preventDefault())
```

But you'll still have problem, like in Chrome you can use up and down arrows to increase or decrease the amount, while in Firefox this gives you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function preventNonNumericalInput(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[JSFiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/4xbr46ov/)